# Strategies for searching through strings in python?

Tags: python, string

What are efficient ways to search for substrings in strings? 
    - Are there specific functions built in python we can use? 
    - Can we convert them to lists then access elements in the list? 
    - Can we use for loops to search through individual elements? 
    - Is there one generally accepted method by Python programmers?

It would be helpful to understand the different strategies to help me solve the following problem:

Return the number of times that the string `"code"` appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the `'d'`, so `"cope"` and `"cooe"` count.

```
count_code('aaacodebbb') → 1
count_code('codexxcode') → 2
count_code('cozexxcope') → 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
def count(s):
    return sum(1 for m in re.finditer(r'co.e', s))
... 
>>> count('aaacodebbb')
1
>>> count('codexxcode')
2
>>> count('cozexxcope')
2
```

Here `.` matches any character, if you only want to match alphabets then use `r'co[a-zA-Z]e'`.

Comment: How could this be done without using a external library?

Comment: `re` is part of the python standard library, so it is no more external than `sys` or `os`.

Comment: as per @robertking s answer -> `'codexxcode'.count("code")` no regex or modules at all!

Comment: I'm curious that why do you use "sum(...)" instead of len(...) ?

Comment: @Tarzan What's the point of creating a list in memory when only count is required as output.

Comment: @Chaudhary Yeah, thank you. I've never noticed that before xD

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression would work for this-

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'co[a-z]e')
li = regex.findall("cozexxcope")           #Output: ['coze', 'cope']
```

Count can be found be the len(li).

Answer (score 0):

```
    def count_code(str):
      count = 0 #set count to 0 initially
        #For loops number of times that there are chars
      for i in range(len(str)-1): 
         #looks for "co", [any char] and "e"
        if str[i:i+2] == "co" and str[i+3:i+4] == "e":  
            #add up the number of times this happens and return it
          count+= 1 
    return count
```

Comment: In addition to providing code, you should explain to OP what/how this code works and why you took this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
def count_code(str):
  count = 0
  for i in range(0, len(str)-3):
    if str[i] == "c" and str[i+1] == "o" and str[i+3] == "e":
      count = count + 1
  return count
```